# How correct is it to use || as "ifnull" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've seen code like this on the web:

```
function MyEventHandler(e)
{
    var ev = e || event;
    var target = ev.srcElement || ev.target
}
```

In essence, the `||` operator is used as a shorthand for `a?a:b`. As far as I can tell - it works on all browsers. But bringing up specs for, say, JScript, [I see](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxxekd04(v=VS.85).aspx):

> Performs a logical disjunction on two expressions.

and

> JScript uses the following rules for converting non-Boolean values to Boolean values:
>
> - All objects are considered true.

So... according to this the result should be a boolean true/false. I'm just wondering - am I walking the knife-edge of undocumented behavior, or is there some fine implication here that I haven't picked up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That behavior is quite well documenten. See Chapter 11.11 of the ECMAScript Specification: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf

Unfortunately it's not very easy to understand, however the last paragraph states:

> The value produced by a && or ||
>   operator is not necessarily of type
>   Boolean. The value produced will
>   always  be the value of one of the two
>   operand expressions.

Answer (score 4):

No, I think you understand the coalescent behavior of `||` just fine.

**EDIT:**

`&&` is also coalescent. `a && b` behaves like `a ? b : a`.

Comment: Where is this documented? Why doesn't it first convert `a` and `b` to booleans?

Comment: It doesn't convert, but evaluate the variable as expression. When the variable is null or undefined it becomes false. The operator always return the value of the variable instead of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

It's just an inaccuracy in JScript specs. JScript is an implementation of the ECMAScript standard, so for the real state of affairs you should look at the ECMAScript spec.